# How to minimize ever changing website style changes using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, css, angularjs-directive, look-and-feel

I really want to minimize the work of ever changing look n feel changes in my website/portal. The changes are sometimes related to only CSS which sometimes wants me to update the name of the classes and most of the times, only internal styles are updated (only in this case changes are transparent). But the real torture comes in when I come to know that there are changes in HTML structure of new style guide and after whole application/widgets need to be updated and aligned according to the new style guide.

Technologies used in the application are: AngularJS, Bootstrap 3

Now, please suggest what would be the best possible way to minimize these style guide changes? Can AngularJS helps me in that?

Thanks,

Jaffy

Comment: Well angularJS is just a JS framework.. Not a style guide.. Something like bootstrap3 // foundation are css frameworks.. They minimize the amountof input you need to commit for style..

Comment: Why are your styles ever changing?

Comment: The application is in demo phase and frontend designer is keep on changing the layouts/styles of the website, which later on I have to incorporate in the real application.

Answer (score 1):

Is not very clear which are your requirements or why your style guide changes. But is not something should try to fix using Angular or Javascript directly. The classes name shouldn't change pretty much never.. except when your layout changes, otherwise the only change should be on the styles.

What you need is 2 things:

1. If you use Foundation or Bootstrap, you should use the SASS/LESS
   files of them and override the styles , that way if the ui
   requirements changes for instance: `background-color`, or
   `border-radius` for certain components, you only need to go to the
   proper `.scss` or `.less` file and change the variable value

You can Import the sass version using

```
bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save
```

Then configure your grunt/gulp or any other task-builder to build sass for instance, and you can override the bootstrap variables.

2. A convention for naming your components, and knowledge of [**OOCSS**](http://oocss.org/) **(Object Oriented CSS)** i recommend you to use [**BEM**](https://en.bem.info/), is very easy to read once you understand the convention and helps a lot with possible css specificity issues.

I hope this helps, otherwise please update your answer more, to understand where are you standing.